# Retrieving MS Access filename when using RODBC

Tags: r, ms-access, rodbc

Typing in my connection name I see a line like `DBQ=Path\to\DB`. How do I retrieve this value? I have tried

- `conn$DBQ`
- `conn[DBQ]`
- `conn['DBQ']`
- `conn[,'DBQ']`

None return the value. I tried `typeof(conn)` and got `"integer"`, `class(conn)` -> `"RODBC"`, `mode(conn)` -> `"numeric"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no simple way. You could get connection string by `attr(conn, "connection.string")` and then try to parse it (e.g.: `sub("^DBQ=([^=]*);.*", "\\1", attr(a,"connection.string"))` or `strsplit(attr(a,"connection.string"),";")[[1]][1]`).